# Tkinter button remains stuck down after pressed as a result of importing another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have created a button that will run some code and in order to organise the code better, I have put this code into another script.

When calling this script using the os module, the button remains stuck down and causes the application to be 'not responding'

Does anyone know a way I can call this other script without causing this button to remain stuck down?

```
self.forgot_password = Button(self.root, text='Forgot Password', font=('Helvetica',7), bg='#411684',fg='#fff', command=self.forgotPassword_window)
self.forgot_password.grid(row=5,column=2)
def forgotPassword_window(self):
    os.system('python forgot.py')
```

Comment: You can execute `os.system()` in another thread

Comment: As long as the the file forgot.py is being alive in the same thread the GUI will freeze

Comment: Use `from subprocess import Popen`.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it in a separate thread, like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['Python', 'forgot.py'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```